# How to put some values from a list into a function in a Do loop

Tags: plotting, functions, programming, function-construction, random

I want to program a code in MATHEMATICA in order to calculate some values in different iteration. For example, assume this list:

`list={1,2,3,4,5}`

Now assume that the function is :

`f1=Function[u,3+u][x]`

I want to use a `Do` loop to orderly put each integer from the `list` into `f1` function and `Do` loop uses 5 iteration (`{i,1,5}`) and gives 5 answers using the values in the list.
For this example, The results will be :

`4
 5
 6
 7
 8`

I wonder if anyone could help me with this problem.

Comment: My guess is that you have tried something along the lines of `Do[f1[list[[x]]],{x,5}]` and that you got nothing as output.  Try telling it to `Print` the output by wrapping the `f1[list[[x]]]` with Print[].  The answer that Christopher Cole provided using `Map` is clearly a better way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to define f1 as

```
f1 = Function[u, 3 + u]
```

since the form you started with would have created the function and then applied it to x.

The easiest way to do what you want is to use Map:

```
Map[f1, list]
```

which has an equivalent syntax

```
f1 /@ list
```

If you really must use a Do loop, you would do it as follows:

```
Module[{result = {}}, Do[AppendTo[result, f1[i]], {i, list}]; result]
```

This is a lot more work.  The Module that wraps the Do loop creates a result symbol to hold your output.  The Do loop iterates over the elements of list, appending the computation of f1 on each element to the result output.

Comment: @ Christopher Thank you so much!!